# Getting MongoDB on Linux to listen to remote connections

Tags: linux, networking, mongodb

I've successfully installed MongoDB on Windows (on a local machine) as a service, but now I want to move MongoDb to a separate server. So I extracted the tarball to a virtual server on network (running linux).

When I connected to the server ("testmongoserver") using PuTTY from my local machine, I started the mongod server and it told me that it was listening to the default 28017 port. The mongo console is also working and allowed me to create a new database (testdb) and add users to it.

However, I could not access the server from remote. When I type `testmongoserver:28017` it doesn't open the HTTP console as `localhost:28017` on my local machine does. I also can't connect using official drivers and providing a connectionstring.

What are the neccesarry steps to install MongoDB on Linux, so that I could access it from a remote machine with a connectionstring and use its HTTP console via `testmongoserver:28017`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the correct Connection Strings? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections Changed any settings? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration

Comment: make sure there is no firewall rule (on either side) that prevents you from connecting to the remote server.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Run netstat -a on mongo server and check a port.
2. Check DNS settings and check that linux server allows external connections.
3. Check that mongodb can accept external/remote connection.

Default port for mongo is 27017.
28017 - port for webstats.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-Ports

Comment: My issue was #3. It was due to the Bind IP set to 127.0.0.1 as @Yves M. describes in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18769861/448876).

Comment: Sometimes, the server needs to be restarted for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 81):

### 1. Bind IP option

Bind IP is a MongoDB option that restricts connections to specifics IPs.

Have a look at your mongod configuration file, most of the time **bind_ip** is set to `127.0.0.1` for obvious security reasons. You can:

1. Add your desired IP by concatenating a list of comma separated values to bind MongoDB to multiple IP addresses.
2. Remove or comment (with `#` character) the `bind_ip` line. But be aware that all remote connection will be able to connect your MongoDB server!

More about `bind_ip` configuration option: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp

Bind IP can also be set as a command argument: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--bind_ip

### 2. Firewall

Check that you are not running behind a firewall

Comment: Should have been chosen as the correct answer. Pinpoints the issue and explains it too.

Comment: I would clarify that to be bale to accept connections on specific network adapter you must set **bind_ip** to the IP of this network adapter. **This is not a filter for incoming connections!**

Answer (score 37):

Make sure in your `/etc/mongodb.conf` file you have the following line,

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

http://jitu-blog.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/allow-mongo-to-connect-from-remote-ip.html

Comment: This is a bad idea from a configuration perspective. You'll achieve the same result from commenting out the bind_ip line. I would encourage comma separating the specific private or public ips of your server:
127.0.0.1,10.x.x.x

Comment: Really BAD idea, specially with new vulnerability when using mongo.

Comment: Yes, it's a BAD idea working with production environment. This setting would be 'acceptable' if env=development. be careful

Comment: I'm in Windows and don't see the file etc/mongod.conf. Where is it or where do i put it exactly? And I tried to put it in my mongodb.config file, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: dev env only. but uncommenting bind_ip DOES NOT allow remote access. It has to be set to 0.0.0.0 to accept connections from remote host. Like others have mentioned, providing a list of IP address that you expect to connect from is the way to do it in prod env.

Comment: The guy who asked the question NEVER said this is a server production. If it's just for development, it's perfectly fine answer. I am running Linux on a virtual machine and I want anyone in my network to access this, what's wrong with 0.0.0.0 in this case?

Answer (score 8):

Just had this issue and this fixed it:

Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` with `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf` ensure that the net section looks like below (localhost binding by default doesn't allow for remote access):

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Make sure to restart mongod when you are done with above with below (assuming systemd ubuntu 16.04+ etc.):

`sudo service mongod restart`

Obviously from a security perspective if you are going to be opening up mongo to your network/the world be aware of the implications of this (if any)

Comment: As in previous post as been point out, you should also make the port 27017, in this case, available. Also you may have security issue, to reduce them you could, as just mentioned, restrict the IPs accesible to the port and/or create a user with a password. I have gone through this recently I make some notes of the whole process here: http://incredulosanonimos.blogspot.co.uk/2018/04/making-mongodb-remotely-available.html.

Answer (score 3):

Another problem may be that the mongodb port is not enabled. Check, from another host, the ports enabled on your server. For that you can use the command:

```
sudo nmap -P0 your_server_ip
```

You can get an answer like this:

```
Host is up (0.052s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
```

If you use a virtual server in the cloud, as AWS, you need to add a new rule to add mongodb port (27017 by default).

**Important**: Note that with this configuration anyone can have access to your database

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To enable remote connections to a MongoDB instance running on Linux and access it via both a connection string and the HTTP console, follow these steps:

1. **Edit the MongoDB Configuration File:**

   - Locate `mongod.conf`, typically in `/etc/mongod.conf`.
   - Change `bindIp` from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` to listen for connections from all IP addresses.

     ```yaml
     net:
       bindIp: 0.0.0.0
       port: 27017
     ```
   - Note: `27017` is the default MongoDB port. HTTP console runs on `28017`.
2. **Enable Security:**

   - In `mongod.conf`, enable authorization:

     ```yaml
     security:
       authorization: "enabled"
     ```
3. **Restart the MongoDB Service:**

   - Restart MongoDB to apply new settings:

     ```bash
     sudo service mongod restart
     ```
4. **Configure the Firewall:**

   - Open MongoDB port in the firewall (e.g., `iptables` for port `27017`):

     ```bash
     sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
     ```
   - Save `iptables` rules.
5. **Create a MongoDB User:**

   - Create a user with appropriate permissions in the `admin` database.
   - Guide: [MongoDB User Creation](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac).
6. **Test Server Port Accessibility:**

   - Verify MongoDB ports accessibility using [Open Port Check Tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/).
7. **Connect Using MongoDB Compass:**

   - Connect using MongoDB Compass with the connection string:

   ```
   mongodb://username:password@testmongoserver:27017/testdb
   ```

Access the HTTP console via `http://testmongoserver:28017` (if enabled and running on port 28017).

**Security Note:**
Ensure strong user credentials and consider SSL/TLS encryption and network filtering for security.