# Installed mongodb on AWS EC2 instance but unable to connect to it

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have installed MongoDB on EC2 Amazon Linux instance. I have set the security group in the way the port SSH 22 and TCP 27017 are opened. Unfortunately when I try to connect executing the command from the ssh console

```
mongo <public-dns-name>:27107/test
```

I get the following error

```
connecting to: <public-dns-name>:27017/test
2014-08-09T15:25:07.966+0000 warning: Failed to connect to xxx.xx.xx.xx:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-08-09T15:25:07.967+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server <public-dns-name>:27017 (172.31.19.26), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Looks like a similar question is answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159737/getting-mongodb-on-linux-to-listen-to-remote-connections)

Comment: I have resolved the issue by modifying the bind_ip field with 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use nginx's stream module since by default nginx settings, it's expecting http.