# connect remotely to mongoDB server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I have installed MongoDB on a fresh Centos7 server.
I have installed MongoDB accroding to this tutrial: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-7/

The installation was completed succsessfully, when I write mongo on the shell this is the output:

> [root@centos-512mb-nyc3-01 ~]# mongo
>
> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
>
> connecting to: test
>
> Server has startup warnings:
>
> 2016-12-31T18:37:11.734+0000 [initandlisten]
>
> 2016-12-31T18:37:11.734+0000 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Readahead for /var/lib/mongo is set to 4096KB
>
> 2016-12-31T18:37:11.734+0000 [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 256KB (512 sectors) or less
>
> 2016-12-31T18:37:11.734+0000 [initandlisten] **          http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead.

I want to connect remotly to mongo via RoboMongo or NodeJS app.
but when I have tried mongo mongodb://138.197.80.108/
I get network unreachable.

There is something that I need to do to connect remotly to mongo?

Thanks :)

BTW -  I havn't set any password\user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MongoDB on Linux to listen to remote connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159737/getting-mongodb-on-linux-to-listen-to-remote-connections)

Answer (score 0):

I have bind machine's IP address according to: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

and added port 27017 to the fire wall tables.