# How to access mongodb remotely in linux

Tags: mongodb

I have successfully installed mongodb into my linux machine.

Please suggest how to access it remotely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MongoDB on Linux to listen to remote connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159737/getting-mongodb-on-linux-to-listen-to-remote-connections)

Answer (score 3):

I worked on it and searched for it. Finally came up with following solution.

1. Importing the Public Key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

2. Creating a List File

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
```

3. Installing and Verifying MongoDB

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
service mongod status
```

4. Creating a user

```
use admin 
db.createUser({user:"<username>", pwd:"<password>", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})
```

5. Try to Login

```
mongo -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase admin
```

6. Set vi /etc/mongod.conf

```
# Comment bindIp with #
service mongod restart
```

7. Allow connections on port 27017, MongoDB default port

```
ufw allow 27017
ufw status
```

8. Enable mongodb authentication on vi /etc/mongod.conf

```
security: 
    authorization: enabled
```

9. To access mongodb remotely the command is:

```
mongo -u <username> -p <password> <ip-address>:27017/<collection-name>
```