# Bind MongoDB to IP address when running as Service

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, so excuse me for a basic question but.

I am running MongoDB (3.6, Professional) on a Windows PC. I have managed to add it as a Windows Service to start automatically on Startup.

However, it binds to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

The IP on that PC is `192.168.1.10` and I would like to access the server from different LAN PCs.

When I run Mongo, I get:

> WARNING: This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be
>   unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip
>    to specify which IP
>             addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
>             bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
>             server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.

So I went to Services.msc, and added --bind_ip_all as a parameter, and restarted the service. But get the same warning. How can I get my MongoDB service to bind to all, or better yet, `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have resolved this, but not sure if it's the right way.

- I removed the service.
- I recreated the service, but added a conf parameter and provided a
  path to my config file.

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod
>   --dbpath=C:\Storage\database\mongodb\data --logpath=C:\Storage\database\mongodb\logs --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.conf" --install

- I created a config file:

> ## Listen to local and LAN interfaces.
>
> ```
> # network interfaces
> net:
>   port: 27017
>   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.10  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
> ```

It seems I can now bind to both localhost and my IP address..

Comment: It is good enough for your  particular case.  Alternatively you could have "bindIp: 0.0.0.0" here there is a discussion about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159737/getting-mongodb-on-linux-to-listen-to-remote-connections .